# Local Only Fields In Redux Toolkit Query

Tags: redux-toolkit

I have a user object and I would like to keep a local, client only property on it.

With Apollo Client, this would look like:

```
query UserProfile($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
        name
        nickname @client # This is a local-only field
    }
}
```

I'm switching to Redux Toolkit query and I'm not sure how to implement this same behavior. I thought it was with `transformResponse` but I'm running into a couple issues with it. One is a Typescript issue which says anything I try to return is not assignable to `undefined` but even when I just ignore this run it anyways, it doesn't seem to ever run.

```
getUserProfile: builder.query<{ name: string }, string>({
    queryFn: async (id: string) => {
        try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .from("user_profile")
                .select("name")
                .eq("id", id)
                .maybeSingle();

            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error.message);
            }

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                error,
            };
        }
    },
    transformResponse: (data: { name: string }): { name: string } & { nickname: string } => {
        console.log("Transforming Response");
        return {
            name,
            nickname: "John",
        };
    }
}),
```

But in the `transformResponse`, the `console.log` is never being called and when I look at the data in the redux toolkit dev tools, the `nickname` property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of RTK Query is to give you a representation of the data on your server - it doesn't have local-only fields, and if you were to use something like `transformResponse`, you'd have no way of updating them without a request to the server.

If you use RTK Query, though, you *do* have the full Redux Toolkit at your fingertips, which is made to enable you to manually store data.

=> Create a separate slice for that data. RTK Query isn't meant to hold it.

Comment: The data in the slice won't be garbage collected so when something is removed from the query cache, the data in the slice will still be there and that's not ideal.

Comment: It's still not "server data", unless it is 100% derived - and in that case, you shouldn't save it to the store at all, but derive it in a selector.